# Getting "Invalid default value" when upgrading Liquibase from 3.2 to 3.3

Tags: mysql, liquibase, default-value, changeset

I was using LIquibase 3.2 and am trying to upgrade to 3.3 and I'm using MySql 5.5.  However, upgrading is failing for the following types of change sets ...

```
<changeSet author="me" id="my_changeset">
    <addColumn tableName="my_table">
        <column name="STUFF_VISIBLE" type="BOOLEAN" defaultValueNumeric="0">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

It fails with the error

```
Error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Invalid default value for 'STUFF_VISIBLE'
```

IS there any way to fix things without having to readjust all the checksums?  There are a number of occurrences of these types of statements in my Liquibase change sets.

Answer (score 0):

For each instance of something like this you could add a `validChecksums` attribute to the changeset that listed the checksum of the changeset before the change as well as after the change.

Comment: Ok thanks for this .  And this would prevent the checksum from running again if the new checksum appeared in the list of valid checksums?

Comment: Liquibase always calculates a checksum for each changeset that is about to be applied to a database. It compares the calculated checksum against the row in the DATABASECHANGELOG table that has the same [changesetid, author, path] as the changeset about to be applied, and if the checksum is different, raises an exception. If the calculated checksum is listed in the validChecksum attribute, that is also considered acceptable and the changeset can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the failed changesets shouldn't be written to the DATABASECHANGELOG table in your DB, so if you change this particular changeset you won't need to recalculate the checksums.
In addition you can always try to rollback the particular changeset or simply open the mentioned DATABASECHANGELOG table and update the exact record in it manually (e.g. remove information about applying changeset :))
BTW: why do you use defaultValueNumeric instead of defaultValueBoolean?